# Sorting MySQL table and then updating the rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to sort the table at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87fa6 by jobs.datetime ascending and then select only rows where `jobs.operator_id=0` and `jobs.status=open`.

Once the table has this structure, I want to set `jobs.operator_id=bidList[i].OperatorId` but this should only happen in rows where `booking.plot_id=bid.plot_id`.

I've bought it down to the following 2 SQL statements - would be possible to combine them somehow so they meet the requirement above?

```
// Allocate jobs to bids
for (var i = 0; i < bidList.Count; i++)
{

    // Select rows where booking.status=open, booking.postcode=_plot and
    // booking.operator_id=0. 
    // Once this is done, order by datetime

    query = "SELECT operator_id, plot_id, status FROM booking " +
            "WHERE status='open' AND postcode='" + _plot + "' AND operator_id=0" +
            "ORDER BY datetime";

    // Whilst maintaining the structure above, set 
    // booking.operator_id=bidList[i].OperatorId, 
    // booking.status=allocated where BidList.PlotId = jobs.plotid

    query += "UPDATE t1 SET t1.operator_id='" +
             bidList[i].OperatorId + "', t1.status='Allocated' " +
             "FROM booking_view T1 "+ "JOIN bid t2 ON t1.plot_id=t2.plot_id";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second query like this:

```
"UPDATE t1 SET t1.operator_id='" +
bidList[i].OperatorId + "', t1.status='Allocated' " +
"FROM booking_view T1 "+
"JOIN bid t2 ON t1.plot_id=t2.plot_id";
```

Comment: Thanks, will it only run the update only on rows that have met the requirements on the first section of the query?

Comment: Btw I was just realised, it is `booking` instead of `booking_view`.

Comment: well I just correct the query, no try to change the update logic, so please tell me the final criteria to make the update, i see too much confusing information.

Comment: Sorry, well in a nutshell I am just trying to combine the two queries above, so that a selection is made and then an update is made only to the selected rows. Is it possible?

Comment: yes its posible, but you need to specify what meaning "combine", so let me try to understand, where clausule is booking T1.plot_id = bid.plot_id and status = 'open' and postcode = '_plot' and operator_id=0 rigth ?. Then the set will be booking.operator1 = bidList[i].OperatorId and t1.status='Allocated', confirme pls, you just need

Comment: Yes and it needs to be sorted by datetime as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69771/discussion-between-methuselah-and-juan-ruiz-de-castilla).